# How do I slow down a Photoshop timeline animation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have created a complex Photoshop *timeline* animation (as opposed to a simple frame animation) that I would like to slow down. By "slow down" I mean increase the time between each frame and correspondingly increase the total duration of the animation. If this was a frame animation it would be easy, but I can't figure out how to do it for a timeline animation.

I see that I can adjust the frame rate of the animation, but doing so keeps the total duration the same, whereas I want to adjust the frame rate *and* the total duration simultaneously.

I'm looking for a solution that does not involve adjusting the frame rate and then manually adjusting all my keyframes (because I have too many to make that an easy process).

Comment: You'd have easier time doing that with After Effects.

Answer (score 2):

In Photoshop's timeline window, right click the layer. The options for duration and speed should open!

Added:

If the video layer is **already in a "Video Group" and a Smart Object Layer**... you have to open the Smart Object, and **then** right click **THAT** internal timeline to adjust the speed/duration.

When you transform or otherwise alter a video layer, you are presented with a dialog....

[image]

Perhaps you missed it or click the "don't show again option". But this essentially tells you the layer structure is changing, which adds a "Video Group" to the Layers panel, and converts the *video layer* to a Smart object (note the icon in the bottom right of the layer thumbnail *is* differnt). So....

If your layers look like this:

[image]

With the video as part of a "Video Group" and as a Smart Object, you need to **double-click** the Smart Object layer. This will open a new window containing *that* video clip. Your layers will look like this:

[image]

Just a straight *video* object *without* the "Video Group".

**Then** you can right-click the timeline to adjust speed and duration:

[image]

You can only adjust speed and duration when a **video layer** is highlighted, because you're then changing the video clip, rather than its possible encompassing smart object.

This works, but it does somewhat depend upon the layer structure of your file regarding *where* you have to click.

Comment: Hmm... I tried right-clicking the names of several of my layers in the Timeline window, but nothing opened.

Comment: @WaltD This has worked for me forever.... however.. if the video is already in a Smart Object Layer... you have to open the Smart Object, and **then** right click THAT internal timeline to adjust the speed/duration. (Note this answer didn't deserve a down vote.. whoever gave it) In fact.. it's correct, just very sparse on information.

Comment: @Scott I tried right-clicking on all kinds of layers (raster, shapes, smart objects) in the timeline window, but in no case did any menu or options open. Maybe I'm not understanding what I'm supposed to be right-clicking on? A screenshot would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Double click the video smart object... it opens in a new window with it's own timeline... right-click *that* timeline and you should see Speed and Duration options.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and fastest method I could find without writing a Script or Action is to use AnimDessin2 (which is great and should be used anyways) then do it keyframe by keyframe. <kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>[ / ]</kbd> combined with the AnimDessin `+ button`. Might be able to turn this into an Action to make it only one button but I'm not sure, I've never tried using Plugins with Actions or Shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your file (for example my green emoji gif) and go to **Timeline** (Window>Timeline)
2. Select convert to video icon

   [image]
3. Click the waffle and select Set Timeline Frame Rate...

   [image]

4.Setup with preferable Frame rate and ok.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as stated in my original question, my animation is already a timeline animation. If I change the animation's framerate via the "Set Timeline Frame Rate" option then it correspondingly changes the number of frames in the animation, keeping the total duration the same. What I want to do is, for example, change a 5 second animation running at 60 fps into a 10 second animation running at 30 fps.

Comment: Than as  **Joonas** said you better of using AF.

Answer (score -1):

You can select all frames in a "frame animation" by clicking on the first, holding shift and then scrolling to the last, and clicking that one.

When all frames are selected, you can change the "Delay" amount by clicking the downward arrow on the bottom of each frame. The delay defines the wait time between one frame and the next.

When all frames are selected, changing the "Delay" time will adjust all frames delay time.

[image: g7JFR.png]

Comment: The OP specifically states that this is NOT a frame animation.

Answer (score -1):

http://photoshopanimation.com/2014/photoshop-frame-rate-essentials/

This link should provide the answer you seek.